# Remove Application Ribbon from new SubArea in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, xrmtoolbox

I want to remove the ribbon that automatically creates when a new SubArea is created with XrmToolBox's SiteMap Editor.

See screendump
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG8QW.png).

Do anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the Application Ribbon. There is some icons that you can hide/unhide at the top of the screen. I think those buttons you automatically get when you create a new SubArea is only shown in the application ribbon, and not in the entities.
Atleast they dissapeared in my solution, by just hiding those buttons in the "home" workspace inside the application ribbon.
There is also some code you can try, but i dont know where :)

Code:

```
Mscrm.BasicHomeTab.New.NewActivity.Hide
```

I think its the same code for all buttons, just different names of course.The code above is for the NewActivity button.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's out-of-box behavior and you can't do anything with it. One thing you can try - open a feature request at [Connect portal](https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/Feedback).